# yarn publish <folder>.gitignore overriding .npmignore

Tags: javascript, publish, gitignore, yarnpkg, npmignore

I'm trying to publish a module I have created.
The module has multiple entries in it and I want to publish from within my build folder.

Every time I try to publish with yarn. I get:

> Output:
>   The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>   build/package.json
>   Use -f if you really want to add them.

I tried `yarn publish build`
And also `cd build && yarn publish` where I copy the package.json and npmignore and all the relevant files.

It's always the same result.

I have a .gitignore in my root and an .npmignore in my root.

If I publish the build folder from the root it works but I dont want the path to include the build/lib folder.

If I do `yarn build && cd build && npm publish && cd ../` that will also work.
But I'd rather use `yarn`.

Does anyone have a solution for it?

All I want is to publish my already created build folder content. I have all the needed files there.

**EDIT**

After much research and looking into other packages,

**I ended up just creating a small copy script that copies my essential files to a build folder and clears up my package.json from all unwanted items**.

Then my ci publishes from the build folder.
That was our solution that we've implemented